# Shortcut for expanding a collapsed tree in Tree-style-tab addon

Tags: firefox, browser-addons

In the firefox addon **tree style tab** ,is there a keyboard shortcut for expanding  a collapsed tree?

Answer (score 5):

Years has passed but pressing F1 hides/show Tree Style Tab. This can be set at `about:addons => 'Extensions' => the gear button => 'Manage Extension Shortcuts' => 'Tree Style Tab' => 'Toggle "Tree Style Tab" Sidebar'`

Comment: Shoot, I hit F1 and it _hid_ it, but another F1 isn't causing it to reappear again. Looks like this is a known bug and restarting Firefox fixes it.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a shortcut based on its API. Here is how:

First, download and install keyconfig.xpi addon from http://mozilla.dorando.at/
With this, create an entry with code:

```
gBrowser.treeStyleTab.collapseExpandSubtree(gBrowser.selectedTab, !TreeStyleTabService.isSubtreeCollapsed(gBrowser.selectedTab));
```

and bind it to an unused shortcut.

Comment: This is a perfectly valid answer. There is no setting for a hotkey in tree style tabs itself, but this solution works for setting a key to toggle collapse/expand the subtree under the currently selected tab. Works perfectly and is awesome in combination with vimperator.

Answer (score 1):

In the current version (`0.17.2016031101`), long `CTRL` press unhides the side bar.

I learned it from the changelog:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tree-style-tab/versions/0.14.2013100901.1-signed

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's entirely what you mean but you can hide the entire 'tab bar' by installing https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/hide-tabbar/. Then it's Ctrl-F11 to hide and un-hide the tab bar.

Comment: This extension is not compatible with the Tree Style Tabs extension. When "hiding" the tab bar with this extension, the Tree Style Tabs sidebar goes blank (i.e. no tabs are shown) but it continues to occupy space on the screen.